# React-Native App Structure - registerComponent('F8v2', setup);

Tags: react-native

I am trying to parse out the structure of the React-Native F8 app from Facebook for iOS.

The index.ios.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const {AppRegistry} = require('react-native');
const setup = require('./js/setup');

AppRegistry.registerComponent('F8v2', setup);
```

I understand and can find the set up file.  But what is 'F8v2' in this instance?  Is this in reference to a folder?  Is this in reference to a component (if so, I cannot find it in the app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This refers to the application name or application key

```
static registerComponent(appKey, getComponentFunc)
```

Check : [AppRegistery](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html)

Answer (score 0):

Every screen component in your app must be registered with a unique name. The component itself is a traditional React component extending React.Component or React.PureComponent

```
registerComponent(screenID, generator);
```